# How to test and develop with asm.js?

Tags: javascript, asm.js

Recently I read `asm.js` spec and it seems cool but is there any environment/tool to develop and test this tool or not? Is that still on spec phase only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try it by using emscripten with ASM_JS=1 and running it in a firefox build from a side branch. Links and more instructions are in these slides about asm.js, http://kripken.github.com/mloc_emscripten_talk/#/

Comment: Note asm.js compilation is [now available in Nightly](https://blog.mozilla.org/luke/2013/03/21/asm-js-in-firefox-nightly/)

Comment: The talk is not terribly informative regarding setup/config.  Download the llvm source, download clang and put it where it asks to be in the  llvm source, make and make install.  

Clone the emscripten repo to use the command emcc to compile c/c++ to js.

Answer (score 2):

Use the '-s' command line option of the compiler, like thus:

```
./emcc -O1 -s ASM_JS=1 tests/hello_world.c
```