# Is there a language very close to javascript converticle to asm.js?

Tags: javascript, asm.js

I have a high interest about javascript performance. And I know asm.js can give a serious boost for that matter.

asm.js can (indirectly) be generated from C/C++ code but I'm way more used to javascript. But of course Javascript cannot be converted into asm.js (imo: if it could it would mean the conversion tool figured out mechanics browsers couldn't).

So is there a language very close to javascript wich can be transformed/converted into asm.js? (I guess it would be strongly typed one)

My goal here is to come with a asm.js code withouth having a huge learning requirement.

Comment: Q. Is asm.js a new language?
A. No, it's just (a subset of) JavaScript, see http://asmjs.org/faq.html

Comment: Yes  indeed [plain JavaScript cannot be compiled to asm.js](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15626611/1048572)

Comment: I don't think C++ syntax is that far away from JS. But really, you will have to learn a new language (that works very different from JS) anyway. I don't think there's a language that is that "close" to JS.

Comment: What do you mean by "interest about js performance"? Is it academic curiosity, or do you have an actual problem with high performance requirements?

Comment: @bergi I plan to write a 3D video game.

Comment: @wero  And I know asm.js is not a language It doesn't mean writing it directly is the best option (or world would have stick with binary code).

Comment: @SergeProfafilecebook: Then I'd suggest to use a 3D library, and not write your engine yourself. For a start, at least.

Comment: @Bergi It wouldn't change performance is a big concern. So the quesion remains.